# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Laravel 7

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-design, migration

I'm trying to add a relationship `1:1` between my Visitor & Contact

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddRelationToVisitorsDRelationToVisitorsContacts extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {


        Schema::table('contacts', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->bigInteger('visitor_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('visitor_id')->references('id')->on('visitors')->onDelete('cascade');

        });

    }


    public function down()
    {

        Schema::table('contacts', function($table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('contacts_visitor_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('visitor_id');

        });

        Schema::table('visitors', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn('contact_id');
        });

    }
}
```

---

When run

```
php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2020_04_16_104641_update_contacts_table_04_16_2020
```

I kept getting

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bheng`.`#sql-e1_1f3`, CONSTRAINT `contacts_visitor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`visitor_id`) REFERENCES `visitors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `contacts` add constraint `contacts_visitor_id_foreign` foreign key (`visitor_id`) references `visitors` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:670
    666|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    667|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    668|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    669|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 670|             throw new QueryException(
    671|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    672|             );
    673|         }
    674| 

      +11 vendor frames 
  12  database/migrations/2020_04_16_104641_update_contacts_table_04_16_2020.php:31
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("table")

      +22 vendor frames 
  35  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest versions of laravel the primary key is biginteger. so you might have to change this

$table->integer('visitor_id')->unsigned();

with this

$table->bigInteger('visitor_id')->unsigned();

Comment: Is this the main issue ? or you just propose this for enhancement;

Comment: Error still persist with your answer `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `contacts` add constraint `contacts_visitor_id_foreign` foreign key (`visitor_id`) references `visitors` (`id`) on delete cascade)` ----- IS it even an answer ?

Comment: this can be the main issue, as the reference column is not the same with the one trying to be created.

Comment: could you please share the table structure for the visitors table?

Answer (score 1):

The id field in the visitors table should be of type **bigIncrement**

Answer (score 0):

If your table has data, it's better to set the column value to null for the data that already exists, or set that column to nullable.

$table->bigInteger('visitor_id')->unsigned()->nullable();